# How do I unit test handlers with NServiceBus?

Tags: unit-testing, nservicebus

This should be simple and I'm probably missing something.  I'm working from here: http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/856297-unit-testing

The following always fails:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void RoundTrip() {
        Test.Initialize();

        var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Test.Handler(bus => new MyHandler(bus))
            .ExpectReply<IEventThatHappened>(m => m.CorrelationId == correlationId)
            .OnMessage<MyCommand>(m => new MyCommand(correlationId));
    }

}

public interface IEventThatHappened : IEvent
{
    Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; private set; }

    public MyCommand(Guid correlationId) {
        CorrelationId = correlationId;
    }
}

public class MyHandler : IHandleMessages<MyCommand>
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    public MyHandler(IBus bus) {
        if (bus == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bus");
        }
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public void Handle(MyCommand message) {
        _bus.Send<IEventThatHappened>(m => m.CorrelationId = message.CorrelationId);
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint inside my handler, the message.CorrelationId == Guid.Empty.  The exception thrown during the test is:

System.Exception : ExpectedReplyInvocation not fulfilled.
Calls made:
SendInvocation

I've tried using bus.Send, bus.Publish, bus.Reply but each one fails with the corresponding Expected*Invocation .

Why is the message.CorrelationId == Guid.Empty instead of the value I supplied?  Why doesn't Test.Handler<> detect that I've called Send/Reply/Publish in my handler?

NOTE: Using NServiceBus 3.3 from Nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.

1. In your handler, you are trying to `Bus.Send()` an event (the `IEventThatHappened` implements `IEvent` and is even named like an event), which is not allowed. Commands are Sent, Events are Published.
2. Your test is using `ExpectReply`, which is what you would expect if the handler were doing `Bus.Reply()`. Assuming you fixed #1, I believe you would be looking for `.ExpectPublish()`.

So first you need to work out what it really is you're meaning to do!

Comment: The 2nd part of my question was "Why is message.CorrelationId == Guid.Empty" is because I was returning a new message instead of updating the one the test framework created.  That was resolved by modifying my command to allow the CorrelationId to be publicy setable and then using this:  `.OnMessage<MyCommand>(m => m.CorrelationId = correlationId)`  

I don't like that, preferring private setters, but I'll explore that later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Reply` instead of `Send`!

Here is the test that passes:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void RoundTrip()
    {
        Test.Initialize();

        var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var myCommand = new MyCommand(correlationId);

        Test.Handler(bus => new MyHandler(bus))
            .ExpectReply<IEventThatHappened>(m => m.CorrelationId == correlationId)
            .OnMessage(myCommand);
    }

}

public interface IEventThatHappened : IEvent
{
    Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; private set; }

    public MyCommand(Guid correlationId)
    {
        CorrelationId = correlationId;
    }
}

public class MyHandler : IHandleMessages<MyCommand>
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    public MyHandler(IBus bus)
    {
        if (bus == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bus");
        }
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public void Handle(MyCommand message)
    {
        _bus.Reply<IEventThatHappened>(m => m.CorrelationId = message.CorrelationId);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried first but it doesn't compile for me.  I get "error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'NServiceBus.Testing.Handler<MyHandler>.OnMessage<TMessage>(System.Action<TMessage>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."